# POST request from javascript getting terminated

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, post

I have the following code that gets executed when button is pressed.

```
function signInButton(){
    var data = {
            "userName" : $("#text_userName").val(),
            "password" : $("#password_signInPassword").val()
        };

    var userName = $("#text_userName").val();
    var password = $("#password_signInPassword").val();

    var loadUrl= parentApp + "/executeLogin.htm";
    makeNetCall(loadUrl, data, function(responseJson) {
            jQuery("#text_userName").val('');
            jQuery("#password_signInPassword").val('');
            post('/TestWebProject/pages/SetSession.jsp', {name: 'Johnny Bravo'});           

    }, 
    function(err) { 
        jQuery("#text_userName").val('');
        jQuery("#password_signInPassword").val('');
        alert("Invalid Username/Password"); 
    });

}
```

but this post request `post('/TestWebProject/pages/SetSession.jsp', {name: 'Johnny Bravo'});` is getting aborted.

post method is

```
function post(path, params, method) {
    method = method || "post"; // Set method to post by default if not specified.

    // The rest of this code assumes you are not using a library.
    // It can be made less wordy if you use one.
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("method", method);
    form.setAttribute("action", path);

    for(var key in params) {
        if(params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
            hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[key]);

            form.appendChild(hiddenField);
         }
    }

    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
}
```

[image]

There is no other request that could abort my post request. Why is this happening then? Any has encountered this before? solution/workaround?

Comment: Have you tried doing this without creating a form in js? You're obviously using jquery - why not just use $.post? Or $.ajax with the post method specified?

Comment: Worked with IE. I am going to kill myself anytime now. Will try your suggestion prior to that!

Comment: Tried it did not help

Answer (score 0):

Read [NS_BINDING_ABORTED Javascript window.location.replace()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624941/ns-binding-aborted-javascript-window-location-replace)

Based on your network output, it looks like you are redirecting to the login while the post is still going on. I'm not sure what the code of `makeNetCall` looks like, but I assume something in there is causing the page to change before the form is even done loading.

Comment: Or maybe that post request tries to redirect at the bottom of the code.