# How to debug TypeScript NS_BINDING_ABORTED for POST-Requests

Tags: typescript, http, post, firefox, caching

I got a simple functionality that calls my backend, via POST-Request. It uses the same wrapper function that is used everywhere in the project, just does "fetch" and is called in some async/await-manner.

body is just static stuff, some ID and two dates. pretty straightforward - the wrapper-function would fail if body weren't supplied at all or similar.

but the request "always" (well, there were one or two successfull tries in about 100 retries) fails with NS_BINDING_ABORTED

[image: some debugger info about the requsts]

Google tells me that message means I had some cache hit and the request was canceled - but cache is disabled, Header-Vars should prevent it AND adding random stuff to the URL doesn't do shit. (sometimes that OPTIONS-call gets through, but POST itself fails still)

nearly all post-requests in that project are done with this exact same wrapper.

Anyone got some ideas where I could look to debug this?

Comment: btw: chrome cancels too, but sends the full body first, so I see requests incomming in my backend - no success for the request though, so it's not a browser-specific problem

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Turns out my request wasn't cancelled due to a cache hit, but due to page reload.

The reload was caused by a form that was submitted after my onclick-event fired, but before my request had any chance to be completed.

**Note**: Always set that type-property on your buttons

Still no idea how to debug that in general, but in my case having the browser clearing it's network-tab and the reason for the next request beeing due to `Initiator: document` should have been a clue, meaning it's not done by some JS, but by some html functionality.

**Further Reading**:

- [NS_BINDING_ABORTED Javascript window.location.replace()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2624941/1366033)
- [MDN Archive - Network Error Codes](https://udn.realityripple.com/docs/Mozilla/Errors#Network_Errors)

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar situation, but this was mostly happening on Firefox, though it did happen once on Chrome.

Our problem ended up being that a form was getting submitted at the same time we used `fetch()` in JS to hit our API and the refresh from the form submission was interfering with the `fetch()`.

So, our solution was to add `preventDefault()` to the top of the function that hits the API and then add `window.location.reload()` to the end of that function so the page would still reload.